# How to upcast return value of a a constructor

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to fix a type mismatch compiler error that I'm getting from the following code, where type inference isn't doing what I want. I have a sealed class and an rxjava stream:

```
sealed class Result {
    data class Success(val logs: List<Log>) : Result()
    data class Failure(val throwable: Throwable) : Result()
    object InFlight : Result()
}

val logs: Observable<List<Log>> = getLogs()
logs.map(Result::Success)
    .onErrorReturn(Result::Failure)
```

> Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction1<@ParameterName Throwable, Result.Failure> but Function! was expected

I can fix the error by explicitly specifying the mapper function return type, which is sort of upcasting from the inferred type `Result.Success` to `Result` like so:

```
        logs.map({ logs ->
            Result.Success(logs) as Result
        })
```

But I was wondering if this upcasting is possible with a constructor function reference, something like `Result::Success as Result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the in inferred type. Because `logs.map(Result::Success)` infers the type `Success` instead of `Result`. Than `.onErrorReturn(Result::Failure)` fails, because it is a `Failure` type.

You can change it to

```
logs.map<Result>(Result::Success)
    .onErrorReturn(Result::Failure)
```

The `<Result>` makes the type explicit.